# why is my json string data missing such as $match,$group when reading the data through argparse

Tags: python, json, argparse

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()


parser.add_argument('-s', '--source', help='delimited list input', type=str)

parser.add_argument('-d', '--desc', help='delimited list input', type=str)

#into the command line

python main.py -s '''[{"type":"mongo","name":"prodmongo","query":"{ '$match': { 'event_code': 'SALE', 'properties.event_data.status': 'SUCCESS', 'properties.event_data.service': {'$in': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}, 'properties.event_data.transaction_date': {'$lt': 'today_date', '$gte':'yesterday_date'} } }, { '$group': { '_id': '$properties.event_data.service', 'count': {'$sum': 1}, 'sale': {'$sum': '$properties.event_data.mrp'} } }, { '$project': { '_id': 0, 'service': '$_id', 'count': '$count', 'sale': '$sale' } }"},{"type":"sql","name":"prod_sql","query":"select service,count(*) as count,round(sum(mrp),2) as sale from demo where Transaction_Date>='{}' and Transaction_Date<'{}' AND Master_Distributor='PW' AND Service in ('a','b','c','d') AND STATUS='SUCCESS' and Apptype !='xyz' group by Service;"}]''' -d "hello"

sources = args.source
print(sources)

#output after reading through parser
[{"type":"mongo","name":"prodmongo","query":"{ : { event_code: SALE, properties.event_data.status: SUCCESS, properties.event_data.service: {: [a, b, c, d]}, properties.event_data.transaction_date: {: today_date, :yesterday_date} } }, { : { _id: .event_data.service, count: {: 1}, sale: {: .event_data.mrp} } }, { : { _id: 0, service: , count: , sale:  } }"},{"type":"sql","name":"prod_sql","query":"select service,count(*) as count,round(sum(mrp),2) as sale from demo where Transaction_Date>={} and Transaction_Date<{} AND Master_Distributor=PW AND Service in (a,b,c,d) AND STATUS=SUCCESS and Apptype !=xyz group by Service;"}]
```

Comment: Take a good look. Which type of "quotes" are consistently missing do you think?

Comment: @NeilLunn wanted this value in the query key to be stored as json string which is a mongo query for that I removed the "quotes" to 'quotes'.Can you suggest any way to get the $match and field starting with $  in  place.

Comment: So how it still not registering to you that the different quotes are not valid JSON and hence the things are removed? It should be pretty obvious if not immediately then certainly after someone points it out and you acknowledge that you can indeed see it.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes I acknowledge it but value is a string for query key then why is argparse removing the fields starting with $

Comment: `argparse` isn't messing with the `-s` string argument.  Look at `sys.argv` to see the strings that were passed to it from the commandline and the shell.  It's the shell that's doing `$` replacements.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting  - try a back slash to escape the `$`:  `\$match`